# Trying to get service property to a component. But keeps coming back as undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

I'm trying to share data between sibling components (The component below is in a for loop, in the view).

I've set up a service, so that I can store a variable, that these sibling components can access. The problem is when I try to access a value from the service, via a component method, it comes back as undefined. I can pass a number into the service and update it, but when I try to retrieve it, I can't do it.

What's interesting is that if you console log the service value in the constructor, it will retrieve something.

Can anybody help with this? I've tried to follow Max's Service chapter as best as I can, but I don't seem to be getting anything.

Service

```
export class ProjectTaskDataService {

  currentTaskId = 0;

  logTaskSelectionChange(selected_task_id: number) {
    this.currentTaskId = selected_task_id;
  }

  public getSelectedTaskId() {
    return this.currentTaskId;
  }
}
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {ProjectTaskDataService} from '../../../../services/project-task-data.service';

    @Component({
      selector: '[app-section-tasks]',
      templateUrl: './section-tasks.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./section-tasks.component.css'],
      providers: [ProjectTaskDataService]
    })
    export class SectionTasksComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() taskItemData: {id: number, name: string, date: string, type: string, status: string}

      taskId: number;
      taskName: string;
      taskDate: string;
      taskType: string;
      taskStatus: string;

      taskSelected = false;

      // This is the value that stores the ID for the current selected task for the section...
      sectionSelectedTaskId: number;


      constructor(private projectTaskDataService: ProjectTaskDataService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
       // console.log(this.taskItemData);
        this.taskId = this.taskItemData.id;
        this.taskName = this.taskItemData.name;
        this.taskDate = this.taskItemData.date;
        this.taskType = this.taskItemData.type;
        this.taskStatus = this.taskItemData.status;

        // Returns 0, if called here
        console.log(this.projectTaskDataService.currentTaskId);
      }

      selectTask(id: number) {
        // This will return 'undefined'
        console.log('Distraction ', this.projectTaskDataService.getSelectedTaskId());
        this.projectTaskDataService.logTaskSelectionChange(id);
        this.sectionSelectedTaskId = this.projectTaskDataService.currentTaskId;
      }
```

Comment: @SiddAjmera `@Input() taskItemData`

Comment: If the Components are Siblings, then you won't be able to pass the data using an `@Input` property. Please share the implementation of the other sibling component as well. If possible, please create a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue.

Comment: Ignore that. That's for something else. Its the 'sectionSelectedTaskId' property of the component. I want to set it to the value in the service, but can't change it, due to being 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
providers: [ProjectTaskDataService]
```

By registering the service in the *component's* providers array, the instance of the component is only shared with this component and its children.

To share the service between sibling components, register it instead in a module's providers array.

Or better yet, if you are using Angular 6 or higher, use the new `providedIn` registration technique for the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
 }
```

This registers the service with the application's root injector, and the service instance is then shared between all of the components of the application.

Comment: Great. That is working, thanks! Just one more question. If a service value is updated through one component, how can I then make an update, by sending that value to the sibling components and storing it into a property inside that component?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, you can use property getters. If you want to ask a new question with a bit of code, I can provide an appropriate example.

Comment: That's correct. I've asked a new question for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730983/angular-updating-component-value-when-service-value-changes

Answer (score 0):

Service is meant to be a singleton,
I guess you have provided the same service in both the component,

```
[provider]="ProjectTaskDataService" in component1
[provider]="ProjectTaskDataService" in component2
```

due to which two instances of service are being created. Now, These services are two separate services making changes in one won't update the changes in another service.
So basically you can provide service in the module level where both components are declared or in the parent component of these components. (Provide in the module it will be better)