# Angular - Updating component value, when service value changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

I have multiple components (in an NgFor loop) that call the same service.

What I would like is that when one component changes a value in that same service, that new value then gets sent to every component that calls that service and subsequently updates that value in a component variable.

I hope that makes sense.

If you need some more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a `BehaviorSubject` (which are often overkill in simple scenarios), you can use simple getters:

Service has some data to share:

```
export class ProductParameterService {
  showImage: boolean;
  filterBy: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Components just use a getter and any template variable bound to the property is automatically updated when the service value changes:

```
get showImage(): boolean {
    return this.productParameterService.showImage;
}
```

In template:

```
                        <img *ngIf='showImage'
                             [src]='product.imageUrl'
                             [title]='product.productName'>
```

If any component anywhere in the application uses the service to change the value of `showImage`, the view will automatically update (leveraging Angular's built in change detection).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much, Deborah.

Comment: So glad I've been able to help @WebDevKid, but I don't really do animation so I don't know the answer to your other question.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a SharedService like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private sharedData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  sharedData$: Observable<any> = this.sharedData.asObservable();

  setSharedData(sharedData) {
    this.sharedData.next(sharedData);
  }

}
```

This service can then be injected in the components where you want to share the data.

To set the data, call the `setSharedData`. To get the latest changes on the `sharedData`, subscribe to the `sharedData$` Observable right in the `ngOnInit` of the component.